# convergence of different line search

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

In optimization, usually we will have a descent direction $p_k$, and choose an optimal step size $\alpha$ that satisfies certain condition to "loosely" minimize $f(x_k + \alpha p_k)$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Alternatively, one can fix $x_{opt}$ and search for $\alpha \in [0,1]$ to minimize $f(\alpha x_k + ( 1- \alpha) x_{opt})$, a practice often used when search space is constrained but convex.

Now I'm curious how the convergence would change if the line search is not a "line." Specificaly, suppose $x_k$ is a matrix and $x_k = v_kv_k^T$, while $x_{opt} = (v_k +h)(v_k +h)^T$ for some matrices $v_k, h$. If I instead search $\alpha \in [0,1]$ for  $f( (x_k + \alpha h)(x_k + \alpha h)^T)$, will the convergence condition change? In general, let $x_k = g(s_k)$ for some function $g$. How is the search $f(g( \alpha s_k + ( 1- \alpha) s_{opt} ))$ different from $f(\alpha g(s_k) + ( 1- \alpha) g(s_{opt}))$?